# Navigated UI5 page is not appearing in the app

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to make a simple Ui5 application with navigation between two views.

Initial view is loading but somehow the next/navigated view is not getting loaded.

Console says

```
Log.js?eval:456 2022-07-17 19:37:36.263800 Did place the view target 'sap.ui.demo.todo.view.AddTask' with the id '__xmlview1' into the aggregation 'pages' of a control with the id 'container-todo---App--App' - EventProvider sap.ui.core.routing.Target 
Log.js?eval:456 2022-07-17 19:37:36.264899 The route named 'addView' did match with its pattern - EventProvider sap.ui.core.routing.Route
```

Message tells me that view navigation is happening and router is able to find the matching routing pattern properly.

But somehow the target view as a page is not shown in the App control

Below is my view

```
<mvc:View
    
    displayBlock="true"
    height="100%"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <App  id="App">
    
    </App>
    
</mvc:View>
```

Initial/Home view

```
<mvc:View
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  controllerName="sap.ui.demo.todo.controller.App"
>
<Page title="My Task Application" id="taskPage" >

  <Table id="idTasksTable"
        inset="false"
        items="{
            path: '/tasks',
            sorter: {
                path: 'Name'
            }
        }">
        <headerToolbar>
            <OverflowToolbar>
                <content>
                    <Title text="Tasks" level="H2"/>
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                    <ComboBox id="idPopinLayout"
                        placeholder="Popin layout options"
                        change="onPopinLayoutChanged">
                        <items>
                            <core:Item  text="Block"
                                key="Block"/>
                            <core:Item  text="Grid Large"
                                key="GridLarge"/>
                            <core:Item  text="Grid Small"
                                key="GridSmall"/>
                        </items>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <Label text="Sticky options:" />
                    <Button text="Add"
                        press="onAdd"/>
                    <Button text="Edit"
                        press="onAdd"/>
                    <Button text="Delete"
                        press="onDelete"/>
                    
                </content>
            </OverflowToolbar>
        </headerToolbar>
        <infoToolbar>
            <OverflowToolbar>
                <Label text="List of Tasks"/>
            </OverflowToolbar>
        </infoToolbar>
        <columns>
            <Column
                width="12em">
                <Text text="Task Name" />
            </Column>
            <Column
                minScreenWidth="Tablet"
                demandPopin="true">
                <Text text="Task Status" />
            </Column>
            
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
                <cells>
                    <ObjectIdentifier
                        title="{taskName}"
                        />
                    <Text
                        text="{status}" />
                    
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
        </Page>
        </mvc:View>
```

Next/navigated to view

```
 <mvc:View
 xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
 
>
  <Page id="nextPage"
    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding"
    showNavButton="true"
    title="Navigated View"
    
  >
   
    <layout:VerticalLayout xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" width="100%">
      <Text text="↑ Nav back"/>
    </layout:VerticalLayout>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

My manifest.json

```
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "sap.ui.demo.todo",
        "type": "application"
    },

    
    "sap.ui5": {
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.75.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.f": {}
            }
        },
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "sap.ui.demo.todo.view.App",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "id": "App"
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "sap.ui.demo.todo.i18n.i18n",
                    "supportedLocales": ["en", "de"],
                    "fallbackLocale": "en"
                }
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "css/styles.css"
                }
            ]
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "async": true,
                "viewType": "XML",
                "path": "sap.ui.demo.todo.view",
                
                "clearTarget": false,
                "bypassed": {
                    "target": "notFound"
                },
            
                "controlId": "App",
                "controlAggregation": "pages"
                
            },
            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "home",
                    "target": "home"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "addView",
                    "name": "addView",
                    "target": "addView"
                }
                
            ],
            "targets": {
                "home": {
                    "type": "View",
                    "name": "Home",
                    "level": 1
                },
                "addView": {
                    "type": "View",
                    "name": "AddTask",
                    "level": 2
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Event handler in the controller.js which does the navigation

```
onAdd: function () {
                this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("addView");
```

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

tbh i can't see where is the Problem that causing this issue. But i would suggest to add a routerclass to your Manifest.json like this=>
"routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router"
i hope this helps.
Regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you make the `home` route point to target `addView`? This way we'll know if the second XML can be rendered at all. If not then there may be a problem with the XML and not with the routing.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have some options to fix your issue.

- Option 1: Using sap.m.routing.Router
- Option 2: Using sap.ui.routing.Router or do not specify router
- Option 3: Write some event handlers

## Option 1: Using sap.m.routing.Router

You need to add a routerClass in your routing configuration as described by etan.

Your configuration should look something like this:

```
"config": {
    "async": true,
    "viewType": "XML",
    "type": "View",
    "path": "sap.ui.demo.todo.view",
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "controlId": "App",
    "controlAggregation": "pages"
}
```

This will tell UI5 that you want to use the for mobile optimized routing. Without this option, the views, that you specified in your targets, are loaded and "just" placed in the `pages` aggregation of App.

[image: Picture after i pressed the back button]

In this picture I removed the `routerClass` setting again and pressed the back button. The aggregation gets updated, as you can see in the console log, but the page does not change. Using the router `sap.m.routing.Router` does setting the correct pages for you.

## Option 2: Using sap.ui.core.routing.Router or not specifying routerClass setting

When you do not specify a routerClass the `sap.ui.core.routing.Router` will be used for routing. This will result in the behaviour presented in the picture above.

In this case your configuration will need to look like this:

```
"config": {
    "async": true,
    "viewType": "XML",
    "type": "View",
    "path": "sap.ui.demo.todo.view",
    "controlId": "App",
    "controlAggregation": "pages",
    "clearControlAggregation": true
}
```

As you can see, I added the setting `clearControlAggregation` to tell the router to remove the present view from the `pages` aggregation.

From the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/902313063d6f45aeaa3388cc4c13c34e) (There seems to be a typo?):

> `clearAggregation` specifies whether the aggregation should be cleared before adding the new view instance.
> When you use the `sap.m.routing.Router` the default is `false`, for `sap.ui.core.routing.Router` it is `true`.
> When using `sap.ui.ux3.Shell` this value should be set to `true`, for `sap.m.NavContainer` to `false` to ensure that the correct content is shown.

## Option 3: Use custom code and event handlers

You could add various event listeners to manipulate the active page of your app. But I would not advice it.

## Example code for navigation

This is the code I am using for the back navigation.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
], function(Controller, History) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.todo.controller.App", {
        onAdd: function() {
            this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("addView");
        },
        onBack: function() {
            var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
            var oHistory = History.getInstance();
            var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

            if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
                window.history.go(-1);
            } else {
                oRouter.navTo("home", true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I reused your views, so the XML code should be fine.